# Generic command for viewing spreadsheet data to inform how many lines to skip

Tags: r, spreadsheet

Is there a generic command to view the top n lines of data in a spreadsheet to inform a decision about how many lines to skip on the actual read in of the data?

I have used readLines() and read_lines() in some circumstances, but I was wondering if there was more basic and perhaps more universal function for checking spreadsheet data across multiple formats (e.g., csv, xls, xlsx) to determine how many lines to skip.

Comment: I usually run a quick test with `readxl::read_excel()`. Actually, the package has many options, maybe some will help you: [https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl)

Comment: There's not a general solution for the same reason there's not a single `read_everything` function in R: formats differ. With binary- or XML-based formats, `readLines` will return terribleness, whereas with a flat file like CSV, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `data.table::fread()` with the **nrows** argument, it lets you decide how many rows to read.
it's also useful for skipping the lines tou would want to skip using the **skip** argument.
see `fread`'s documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.10.4-2/topics/fread).